# how write a rule to Hide url parameter using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am trying to rewrite URL using htaccess.
i need

```
1>   temp.example.com/save.php?item=xxxxx&id=xxx&type=1 
2>   temp.example.com/save.php?item=xxxxx&id=xxx&type=2
```

to be like

```
1>   temp.example.com/save/xxxxx/xxx
2>   temp.example.com/save/xxxxx/xxx
```

have to hide last parameter .

my htaccess has

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/save\.php\?item=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s&id=([_0-9a-   zA-Z-]+)\s&type=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^temp/save/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^temp/save/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /save.php?item=$1&id=$2&type=$3 [L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not want `type` parameter's value in `temp.example.com/save/example/2`? Do you always want `type=1` to be statically added to `save.php`?

Comment: yes type is kind of static, that's why no need to show

Comment: You cannot hide `type` now since it is not static anymore as it has value `1` and `2` that you will need in `save.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /save\.php\?item=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+)&type=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ save/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^save/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ save.php?item=$1&id=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: i have my code in sub domain . this will work for temp.example.com ?

Comment: That means you didn't place it in root .htaccess. See updated rule. I have already tested it and it worked fine for me on my Apache.

Comment: I have already tested it from root ,htaccess and it worked fine. Make sure you have just these 2 rules when you test it.

Comment: and sir, type can be type=1 or type=2

Comment: I don't get that question, you only replied that `type is kind of static` so put whatever static value here.

Comment: Sorry for confusion . please check the question edit

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^save.php/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ /save.php?id=$1&order_id=$2&page_no=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

now you can access three parameter by pass like
temp.example.com/save/par1/par2